# React Native - play animation backwards with useRef? Error - 'undefined is not an object?'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, lottie

Alright, I'm using functional components and have successfully played a Lottie animation with `useRef` per this answer- [React Native - properly play Lottie on tap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63004808/react-native-properly-play-lottie-on-tap/63006306#63006306)

This is great for just `.play()` but I need to play the animation backwards if it has already been tapped (meaning progress=1). I looked at [React Native Lottie - Upon Animation End Reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51841623/react-native-lottie-upon-animation-end-reverse) and have tried to reverse the animation with the following code, but `LottieRef.current.progress` is `undefined`

The functional component:

```
function NavDot(props) {

        const LottieRef = useRef(null);

        return (
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {
              onNavPress(props.id);
              //LottieRef.current.play();
                  Animated.sequence([
                      Animated.timing(
                          LottieRef.current.progress,
                          {
                            toValue: 1,
                            duration: (5000),
                          }
                        ),
                        Animated.timing(
                          LottieRef.current.progress,
                          {
                            toValue: 0,
                            duration: (5000),
                          }
                        )
                  ]).start();

            }}>
              <LottieView
                  ref={LottieRef}
                  style={styles.lottieNav}
                  source={require('./assets/circle.json')}
                  loop={false}
              />
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        );
      }
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `progress` is a prop from

Althought you aren't passing this prop.

Please refer to this doc to check the right way.

https://github.com/react-native-community/lottie-react-native#usage

---

#### First

You need to create a `progress` state.

So you should have something like this in you function component.

```js
const [progress, setProgress] = useState(new Animated.Value(0))
```

---

#### Second

You need to use this `progress` variable as a prop to LottieView

```js
<LottieView
  ref={LottieRef}
  style={styles.lottieNav}
  source={require('./assets/circle.json')}
  loop={false}
  progress={progress} // <------- Add this
/>
```

---

#### Third

I'm not sure, but if think you can already use the `LottieRef.current.progress`. But in case if not. Use your progress variable like this.

```js
Animated.sequence([
  Animated.timing(
    progress, // <------ Change here
    {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 5000,
    }
  ),
  Animated.timing(
    progress, // <------ Change here
    {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 5000,
    }
  )
]).start();
```

---

I hope it can help you. But try to read all the documentation from react-native-community, it has a great explanation about all what I've been simplified here.